# How can I prevent angular @hostlistner directive from invoking a show menu display function every time outside clicked

Tags: angular, angularjs, drop-down-menu, addeventlistener, preventdefault

I have a menu icon I want to toggle the display. It should show when the icon is click and hidden when any part of the window is clicked. But its always hidden and from my console log i can see @HostListener is always running on any click

Here is my Code

```js
 showMenu(event) {
    this.isShowMenu = this.isShowMenu ? false : true;
    console.log("show menu", this.isShowMenu); 
  }
  
   @HostListener('window:click', ['$event.target']) clickedOutside($event){
   
   if (this.isShowMenu ) {
    this.isShowMenu = false
   }
   }
```

```html
<div class="top-bar-inner">
          <div class="navbar-icon">
            <app-font-icon
              iconType="remix"
              iconName="menu-line"
              iconSize="nav-icons"
              iconColor="#fff"
              (click)="showMenu($event)"
            >
            </app-font-icon>
            <div [class]="isShowMenu ? 'menu':'hide' ">
              <ul>
                <li class="ion-activatable ripple-parent">Profile <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="ion-activatable ripple-parent" (click)="showOfflinePage()">Status <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="ion-activatable ripple-parent">Your Earning <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="ion-activatable ripple-parent">Logout <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-title">
            <h1>Dispactcher</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is the value in $event passed to showMenu method?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this solved. The problem was that @Hostlistener will always fired whenever window is clicked. So clicking the icon invoke my function `showMenu()` and then @Hostlistener function which always sets the variable `this.isShowMenu` back to *false* in contrary to `showMenu()`. Therefore, nothing will show.

Below is my correction

```js
 stopHostlisterFromOtherEvent: boolean = true;

  showMenu(event) {
    this.isShowMenu = this.isShowMenu ? false : true;
    this.stopHostlisterFromOtherEvent = false;
    console.log("show menu", this.isShowMenu); 
  }
  
    @HostListener('window:click', ['$event.target']) clickedOutside($event){
   
   if (!this.stopHostlisterFromOtherEvent && this.isShowMenu ) {
    this.stopHostlisterFromOtherEvent = true;
    console.log("i work 1");
    
   }
   else if(this.stopHostlisterFromOtherEvent && this.isShowMenu ) {
    this.isShowMenu = false;
   }
   else {}
  }
```

```html
<div class="top-bar-inner">
          <div class="navbar-icon">
            <app-font-icon
              iconType="remix"
              iconName="menu-line"
              iconSize="nav-icons"
              iconColor="#fff"
              (click)="showMenu($event)"
            >
            </app-font-icon>
            <div [class]="isShowMenu ? 'menu':'hide' ">
              <ul>
                <li class="ion-activatable ripple-parent">Profile <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="ion-activatable ripple-parent" (click)="showOfflinePage()">Status <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="ion-activatable ripple-parent">Your Earning <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="ion-activatable ripple-parent">Logout <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-title">
            <h1>Dispactcher</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
```